# Setting variable values via an IF statement in Swift

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift. I am generating a random number (0 or 1) using the following:

```
var locValueDeterminer = Int.random(in: 0...1)
```

Based on the output of this, I want to set a variable appropriately:

```
if locValueDeterminer = 0 {
    var loc1Value : NSNumber = 0.5
    var loc2Value : NSNumber = 1
}
else {
    var loc1Value : NSNumber = 0.0
    var loc2Value : NSNumber = 1
}
```

However this returns many errors. What would be the correct conditional statement to use here?

Thanks

Comment: Why use `NSNumber`? Use `Double`, or `Int`, or some other specific Swift type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `==` you wrote `=` in your if statement, and by the way here's a shorter version of that code

```
let locValueDeterminer = Int.random(in: 0...1)
    
let loc1Value = locValueDeterminer == 0 ? 0.5 : 0.0
let loc2Value = 1.0
```

Asking what `locValueDeterminer == 0 ? 0.5 : 0.0` means?-

it's equivalent to `condition ? something : something else`

So in a way it translates to:

```
if locValueDeterminer == 0{
   loc1Value = 0.5
}else{
   loc1Value = 0.0
}
```

Comment: It's called the *ternary conditional operator* and is available in many languages like C, Javascript, PHP. It's not unique to Swift

Answer (score 3):

Ternaries are nice but that may not always be what you want to use. You can declare a let without a value, and assign it within an if/else block.

```
let loc1Value: Double
let loc2Value: Double
if Int.random(in: 0...1) == 0 {
    loc1Value = 0.5
    loc2Value = 0.0
} else {
    loc1Value = 0.0
    loc2Value = 0.0
}
```

Comment: This answer is less specific to the OP's problem, but feels like a better answer to the OP's general question, extending it to let constants as well as vars.

Answer (score 1):

If your intend is to generate a true/false random condition in Swift 4 you can simply use Bool's random method:

```
let loc1Value = Bool.random() ? 0.5 : 0
```